# How to present cases when writing a proof.

Tags: proof-writing

I was writing a proof where I wanted to show a statement y is true and ended up with two different cases to consider which were essentially: $x = 1$ and $x \neq 1$. I showed the result I wanted is true in both cases and I was just wondering how I would phrase the resulting conclusion. Essentially I want to say "We have $x = 1$ or $x \neq 1$.  Since y is true if $x = 1$ and and y is true if $x \neq 1$, y must be true." What would be the best way of phrasing this so my intention is clear?

Comment: In such a stark case, I would just remark something like "Of course, we must have $x=1$ or $x\neq 1$.  Case I:  $x=1$....".  It's tougher when it isn't obvious that the cases exhaust all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably write it like this:
"At this point of the proof, we have two different cases: $x=1$ and $x \neq 1$.
First, if $x=1$, then ..., and $y$ is true.
Otherwise, we have ... and $y$ is also true.
Since it is true in both cases, $y$ must be true."